# How to hide then logout link using spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security, thymeleaf

I'm working with spring security and thymeleaf ,i want to  hide the logout link if user is not authenticated and i don't know how to do that.
Could anyone please help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enclose your page content (what you want to hide) in this (sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()") tag, like below:

```
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">
< Hide your stuff here >
</div>
```